# Boolean parameter in a dll function in delphi 7

Tags: delphi, dll, boolean

I have a dll library. I have excluded memory unit for delphi types.

In that way, what would be the appropriate `Boolean` type for function declaration?

Is it `BOOL` or something else?

The problem is that in the method signature:

```
function Test(Param1: BOOL; Param2: BOOL; docContent: PCharArray): Integer;
```

I get AV when program leaves that function.

I assume that it is the problem with the data type of these two first parameters.

Comment: From my experience boolean never causes a AV. PCharArray is my candidate. Is it a input or output Buffer?

Comment: It is: PCharArray = array of PChar; Strange ... now My error has dissappeared ... :|

Comment: "array of PChar" is a dynamic array so you need to use ShareMem-unit in both your dll and main project. Or use a fixed size array "array[0..9] of PChar".

Comment: Or use `PPAnsiChar`, and pass the number of `PAnsiChar` elements in a separate parameter.

Answer (score 6):

`BOOL` is fine for Boolean types. It's a Windows type, so it's what you'll see in all the functions in *Windows.pas*.

Access violations upon return from a DLL function often indicate that you have the calling convention wrong — the default calling convention is `register`, but you probably need `stdcall` or `cdecl`. Add it at the end of the declaration:

```
function Test(Param1: BOOL; Param2: BOOL; docContent: PCharArray): Integer; stdcall;
```

Comment: 1. Well it worked with cdecl. What is it?
2. When i run the method like this procedure(false, false, param) it also did worked, but when I placed boolean parameters: procedure (booleanParam, booleanParam2, param) it didn't

Comment: Don't *guess* what calling convention to use. Find out what the DLL *really* uses, and then specify that in your Delphi declaration. That may or may not be the actual problem, but getting it wrong can cause any manner of failure, so eliminate that possibility before exploring others.

Comment: The dll is mine, also written in delphi 7. Which thing in a dll determines the calling convention?

Comment: If you're responsible for writing both sides, then you just have to make sure both use the same thing, whatever it is. DLLs usually use stdcall.

Comment: besides I guess that in case the library is written in delphi the calling convention should be default (register)? So the problem is somewhere else ..

Comment: In your dll you have lines like `function Test1(i: Integer; b: Boolean; d: Double): Integer; **stdcall**; external 'DEMODLL.DLL' Index 1;` Make sure you specify the calling convention explicity in your dll and the program stat uses it. stdcall is recommended so your dll will also work with outer compiler <> Delphi.

Comment: Paul, if your program only works when the function uses cdecl, but not when both the DLL and the EXE use some other calling convention, then the calling convention is not the problem. I think you have the answer to the question you asked, which was about whether BOOL was an appropriate type to use. You should ask a new question about your access violation; in it, include a minimal compilable example that demonstrates the crash.